# Making sure all partitions are loaded in Hazelcast cluster

Tags: partitioning, hazelcast

Official documentation for distributed map says 'EAGER means load is blocked till all partitions are loaded.' Does it mean any operation with distributed map is blocked until all partitions for that map is loaded?

My project has several pretty big storages and initial loading from DB takes roughly 20 mins. It would be practically unnecessary to start all scheduled tasks to run until all partitions are fully loaded. Is there any wan to get notified when all partitions are up and ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. No operation for a partition will be executed if the partition has not been loaded yet. The operations will be parked and retried.
Load for each partition is independent from one another so if load for partitionId == 1 is done, and you do map.get(key), for a key that is handled by partitionId == 1, this operation will succeed, even though partitionId == 2 is still loading the values. If you want to block until all partitions are loaded on a calling party you can just invoke map.size() it needs all partitions to be loaded, so it won't finish till everything has been loaded.